# Change node.js project name after installing Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and just went through basic tutorials and now ready to set my project with Express.js installed as well.

I'm just wondering what happens if I change my project name to something else now that I've got the framework in place. Can I simply just rename the project directory or do I need some npm package to refactor it properly?

With Ruby on Rails, there is a gem for this purpose and wonder if it's the same for node.js project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I simply just rename the project directory?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Express is just a library.

Express-generator (which proviedes "express" command line) is a tool (not actually a framework) to easily build a basic project layout with express, jade and a few other common packages.

Out of the box you can run it by executing ./bin/www (or node bin/www).

Until now, project name doesn't care so far except for if you put it in some template, database register, etc...

Sure you will use some version control system (vcs) like git or subversion and, if you don't want to publish it as npm module, you doesn't need nothing more.

But, even if you doesn't plan to publish it at npm, it is a wonderful tool to manage your project packaging.

If you did it, (by executing "npm init"), then you can take advantadge of some facilities like:

- Launch your project with 'npm start'.
- Install modules with 'npm --save module_name'.
- DON'T track node_modules directory in your vcs.
- Get fresh node_modules directory for your current node version with 'npm install'
- etc...

All this magic is thanks to a file named 'package.json'.

This file was generated when you did (if you did it) 'npm init' and contains a package name and a version number.

If you doesn't plan to publish your package it also doesn't care so much. But it is a bit more polite to update it accordingly if you rename your project.